# R (ESS) freezes emacs when asking for project directory

Tags: ess, r

Using Windows. Fresh install of emacs 2.6.
The installation of R CLI and R studio worked ok. No issues.
 I open R files on emacs and ESS mode is properly set on modeline but when I try to execute/eval a line or paragraph (C-x C-r or C-RET) Emacs asks for "R starting Project directory".
I accept the offered path and emacs freezes. The only thing I can do is killig it from task manager because close window does not work. Emacs is unresponsive.

Tried to open R terminal wwith M-x R freezes emacs too.
Tested on two different machines using plain simple emacs and Vincent Goulet Modified Emacs for windows
https://vigou3.gitlab.io/emacs-modified-windows/
same results on both

Comment: I have almost the same when I try to do it with Julia backend. But for me `C-g` unfreezes it and afterwards it works.

Comment: C-g not working for me. I have to use task manager and kill emacs process